# Search for specific key word using twitter api and spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I was trying this code and I replaced # with #Apple.

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext("local[*]", "PopularHashtags", Seconds(1))
val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)
val statuses = tweets.map(status => status.getText())
val tweetwords = statuses.flatMap(tweetText => tweetText.split(" "))
val hashtags = tweetwords.filter(word => word.startsWith("#"))
val hashtagKeyValues = hashtags.map(hashtag => (hashtag, 1))
val hashtagCounts = hashtagKeyValues.reduceByKeyAndWindow( (x,y) => x + y, (x,y) => x - y, Seconds(1000), Seconds(1))
val sortedResults = hashtagCounts.transform(rdd => rdd.sortBy(x => x._2, false))
sortedResults.print
```

But I didn't get any results.

Does this streaming have some limit to how many tweets and from which region it will fetch the tweets?
Also I tried looking for #OPPO as in my twitter account this was trending so I tried looking for it but still I didn't get any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext("local[*]", "PopularHashtags", Seconds(1))
//The keyword you want to look for can be specified in a sequence as follows
var seq:Seq[String] = Seq("#Rajasthan","#Apple")
val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, seq)
val statuses = tweets.map(status => status.getText())
val tweetwords = statuses.flatMap(tweetText => tweetText.split(" "))
val hashtags = tweetwords.filter(word=>word.contains("#"))
val hashtagKeyValues = hashtags.map(hashtag => (hashtag, 1))
val hashtagCounts = hashtagKeyValues.reduceByKeyAndWindow( (x,y) => x + y, (x,y) => x - y, Seconds(1000), Seconds(1))
val sortedResults = hashtagCounts.transform(rdd => rdd.sortBy(x => x._2, false))
sortedResults.print
```